# ExactTarget - Salesforce Integration: Adding the report or Campaign to the 'Individual Email Results' record in Salesforce

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud, api, reporting, campaign

I am asking the following on behalf a client.

A features in a system requires the ‘Campaign’ and ‘Report’ field to be completed on the Individual Email Result (and for that matter on the ‘Email Result’ object).

Current situation:
‘Guided Send’ creates a ‘Send Definition’ with the field ‘Report’ or ‘Campaign’ completed depending on what data was used – fine. However (mater-detail to) ‘Email Results’ doesn’t contain the Report/Campaign field and neither does the (master-detail) to ‘Individual Email Results’.

Is there any way to automatically update these child and ‘child of child’ objects – or will it require a trigger in Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to see the Campaign or Report associated with the email send?

If so, and it's a campaign, then you would see that displayed under "Campaign History" section on the Lead record.

If you're sending to a Report and want to add the Lead to a Campaign for tracking purposes you can add ampscript to the email that will do this:

```
SET @CampaignAdd = CreateSalesforceObject("campaignmember", 2, "CampaignId", "701a0000002McNj", 
    "LeadID", @Id
    )
```

You would want to add some error handling to make sure you don't try and add the same Lead to a Campaign twice.